# Why the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n$ does not converge on the unit circle $\{z:|z|=1\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

For the power series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n$, I know its radius of convergence is 1 and it diverse on the boundrary of the disc of convergence. But I fail to prove the latter fact, i.e., it diverse on the boundrary of the disc of convergence. However, the cases that $z=1$ and $z=-1$ are obvious.

Moreover, I know that, if I want to show the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n$ diverse for some $z$, I neeed to find some $\epsilon>0$ so that, for any $N$, there exsits some $N_0>N$ such that $|\sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty}nz^n|>\epsilon$. But I just do know how to find out this $\epsilon$.

Comment: Consider what happens for $z=-1$.

Comment: I know the case $z=1$ or $z=-1$, how about the other case?

Comment: "if I want to show the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n$ diverse for some $z$, I neeed to find some $\epsilon>0$ so that, for any $N$, there exsits some $N_0$ such that $|\sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty}nz^n|>\epsilon$" No, this is not how one shows that a series $\sum\limits_{n}a_n$ diverges. To begin with, to manipulate $\sum\limits_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n$ for some $N$, one must assume beforehand that the series $\sum\limits_{n}a_n$ converges. Please reread your notes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $z \in S:=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ it also holds $z^n \in S$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (since in this case $|z^n|=|z|^n=1^n=1$).

Thus, the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n=nz^n$ does not converge to zero which is necessary for the corresponding sum $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{a_n}$ to be convergent. Hence this sum does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ has an absolute value of $n+1$ when $z$ has an absolute value of $1$. So no convergence. Actually, the partial sums must be unbounded because one of $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ must have an absolute value greater than $\frac{n}{2}$, which is stronger than just not converging.